# how to use a template dialog panel for multiple buttons?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I'm writing a GUI in java. I have a JXTable in which I currently only have static data, but I want allow the user to input data by using a template panel that I have created.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Template_StackOverflowExample extends JPanel{

    private JPanel diagPanel = new dialogTemplate();
    Object[] columnIdentifiers = {
        "id",
        "imei",
    };

    Object[][] data = {
        {"1", "123"},
        {"2", "123"},
        {"3", "123"}
    };

    private JDialog dialog;
    private static DefaultTableModel model;

    public Template_StackOverflowExample(){ 
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JButton addRow = new JButton("Add Row");
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                openRowPane("Add Row");
            }
        });
        JButton editRow = new JButton("Edit Row");
        editRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                openRowPane("Edit Row");
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        TitledBorder buttonBorder = new TitledBorder("Buttons");
        buttonPane.setBorder(buttonBorder);

        buttonPane.add(addRow);
        buttonPane.add(editRow);

        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnIdentifiers);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            model.insertRow(i, data[i]);
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        pane.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        pane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void openRowPane(String name){
        if(dialog == null){
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
            if(win != null){
                dialog = new JDialog(win, name,    ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                dialog.getContentPane().add(diagPanel);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        }
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCVE");      
        Template_StackOverflowExample mainPanel = new     Template_StackOverflowExample();
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class dialogTemplate extends JPanel{

    private JComponent[] content;
    private String[] labelHeaders = {
        "ID:",
        "IMEI:",
    };

    public dialogTemplate(){
        JPanel diagTemplate = new JPanel();
        diagTemplate.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel rowContent = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        JLabel idLabel = null;
        JLabel imeiLabel = null;

        JLabel[] labels = {
            idLabel,
            imeiLabel,
        };

        JTextField idTextField = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField imeiTextField = new JTextField(20);

        content = new JComponent[] {
            idTextField,
            imeiTextField,
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
            labels[i] = new JLabel(labelHeaders[i]);
            rowContent.add(labels[i]);
            rowContent.add(content[i]);
            labels[i].setLabelFor(content[i]);
        }

        JButton save = new JButton("Save"); 
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                closeWindow();
            }
        });
        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                closeWindow();
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        buttonPane.add(save);
        buttonPane.add(cancel);

        buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        diagTemplate.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        diagTemplate.add(rowContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(diagTemplate);
    }

    public void closeWindow(){
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        if(win != null) {
            win.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

As you might see both of the buttons in the pane creates the dialog that is created first ("Add Row" or "Edit Row"). I want them to create different dialogs so that the editing of data doesn't conflict with the addition of data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a different dialog-creating method to each button so you can open two dialogs:

```
    public void openRowPane(String name){
        if(dialog == null){
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
            //change modality
            dialog = new JDialog(win, name,    ModalityType.MODELESS);
            dialog.getContentPane().add(diagPanel);
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void openRowPane2(String name){
        if(dialog2 == null){
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
            //change modality    
            dialog2 = new JDialog(win, name,    ModalityType.MODELESS);
            dialog2.getContentPane().add(diagPanel2);
            dialog2.pack();
            dialog2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        }
        dialog2.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: I believe I tried this already, but I'm gonna give it an extra go.

Comment: Yup. This fixed the problem. Now I just need to figure out how I can create new panels on every open action. Thanks! :D

Comment: Glad it help. Please not the change in modality. That  diagPanel2 is actually a new panel.

Comment: Yeah. My problem is that if I input information to either of the two dialogs it is saved in the dialog when they are closed. I want it to create a completely new panel (without information in it) on every openRowPane method call.

Comment: I think that according to stackoverflow's conventions this have to be a new question. Post one ( an [MCVE] is best) , post a link here and I'll try yo help.

Comment: You are completely right. So here it is ;) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219675/saving-data-and-creating-a-new-panel-without-that-data-in-it)

Comment: I did however not see that you changed the Modality. What does this do? I just tried changing the modality to "Modeless" and got handed a null pointer exception as I tried to "fetch" the data from that JDialog which was not "set" yet.

Comment: As far as I've understood the `ApplicationModal` "hangs" the program and then returns when the JDialog is closed, which is what I want.

Comment: With ApplicationModal you will have to close one JDialog before opening a new one

Comment: I see. Well that does also make a lot of sense. I wouldn't want the user editing and adding at the same time.