# Saving data and creating a new panel without that data in it

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a GUI in Java and I have a layout in which you can find a JTable and two buttons to "manipulate" the JTable (functionality still missing though). Whenever one of the two buttons is clicked a panel should come up in which the user can input information followed by clicking the save button upon when the data is saved.

[image: example screenshot]

As it might be clear from the design of the frame visible I want the Add Row button to add a new Row to the JTable while the Edit Row button should change the data.

## So here are my two problems:

### 1

How do I save what data has been input (preferably in memory) in the new JDialog I open when I click save. Right now I use the `saveData()` method and a global `Object[]` known as `lastData`. Is there a better method? Besides I can't get this to work.

### 2

How do I make sure that I open a NEW JDialog (without previous inputs in it) every time I click either of the two buttons. They use the same template for the panel that they open.
The difference is that the Edit Row button takes the content from the `JTable` and input that to the textfields (not shown in this MCVE). My problem is that if I input something in the Add Row JDialog the input is still there when I open the dialog the next time. How do I either create a new JDialog on every open or clear the data from the JDialog in the best manner?

## Here's a MCVE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test extends JPanel{

    private dialogTemplate diagPanel1 = new dialogTemplate();
    private dialogTemplate diagPanel2 = new dialogTemplate();
    Object[] columnIdentifiers = {
        "id",
        "imei",
    };

    Object[][] data = {
        {"1", "123"},
        {"2", "123"},
        {"3", "123"}
    };

    private JDialog addDialog;
    private JDialog editDialog;
    private static DefaultTableModel model;
    private JTable table;

    public Test(){ 
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JButton addRow = new JButton("Add Row");
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                openAddRowPane("Add Row");
            }
        });
        JButton editRow = new JButton("Edit Row");
        editRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                openEditRowPane("Edit Row");
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        TitledBorder buttonBorder = new TitledBorder("Buttons");
        buttonPane.setBorder(buttonBorder);

        buttonPane.add(addRow);
        buttonPane.add(editRow);

        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnIdentifiers);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            model.insertRow(i, data[i]);
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        pane.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        pane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void openAddRowPane(String name){
        if(addDialog == null){
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
            if(win != null){
                addDialog = new JDialog(win, name,    ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                addDialog.getContentPane().add(diagPanel1);
                addDialog.pack();
                addDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        }
        addDialog.setVisible(true);
        printRow(diagPanel1.getData());
    }

    public void openEditRowPane(String name){
        if(editDialog == null){
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
            if(win != null){
                editDialog = new JDialog(win, name,    ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                editDialog.getContentPane().add(diagPanel2);
                editDialog.pack();
                editDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        }
        editDialog.setVisible(true);
        printRow(diagPanel2.getData());
    }

    public void printRow(Object[] data){
        int length = data.length;
        String s = "[";
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(i == length-1){
                s += data[i].toString() + "]";
            } else {
                s += data[i].toString() + ", ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCVE");      
        Template_StackOverflowExample mainPanel = new     Template_StackOverflowExample();
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class dialogTemplate extends JPanel{

    private JComponent[] content;
    private String[] labelHeaders = {
        "ID:",
        "IMEI:",
    };

    private Object[] lastData;

    public dialogTemplate(){
        JPanel diagTemplate = new JPanel();
        diagTemplate.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel rowContent = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        JLabel idLabel = null;
        JLabel imeiLabel = null;

        JLabel[] labels = {
            idLabel,
            imeiLabel,
        };

        JTextField idTextField = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField imeiTextField = new JTextField(20);

        content = new JComponent[] {
            idTextField,
            imeiTextField,
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
            labels[i] = new JLabel(labelHeaders[i]);
            rowContent.add(labels[i]);
            rowContent.add(content[i]);
            labels[i].setLabelFor(content[i]);
        }

        JButton save = new JButton("Save"); 
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveData();
                closeWindow();
            }
        });
        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                closeWindow();
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        buttonPane.add(save);
        buttonPane.add(cancel);

        buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        diagTemplate.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        diagTemplate.add(rowContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(diagTemplate);
    }

    public void saveData(){
        lastData = new Object[content.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < lastData.length; i++){
            if(content[i] instanceof JTextField){
                JTextField temp = (JTextField) content[i];
                lastData[i] = temp.getText();
            }
        }
    }

    public Object[] getData(){
        return lastData;
    }

    public void closeWindow(){
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        if(win != null) {
            win.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

As a small side note I have implemented creating adding and editing rows in the table in my own example and they have been left out of this MCVE. In this example I just want to see that I get some "data", hence the `printRow()` method.

Comment: It doesn't compile. Names of JDialogs are inconsistent.

Comment: Sorry. Fixing it asap.

Comment: @c0der: It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the compilation errors and answered you 2nd question. See comments :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Template_StackOverflowExample extends JPanel{

    //changed type to DialogTemplate so you can use getData()
    //Alternatively you can keep the type as JPanle and cast:
    // ((DialogTemplate)diagPanel1).getData()
    private DialogTemplate diagPanel1 = new DialogTemplate();
    private DialogTemplate diagPanel2 = new DialogTemplate();

    Object[] columnIdentifiers = {
        "id",
        "imei",
    };

    Object[][] data = {
        {"1", "123"},
        {"2", "123"},
        {"3", "123"}
    };

    private JDialog addDialog;
    private JDialog editDialog;
    private static DefaultTableModel model;
    private JTable table;

    public Template_StackOverflowExample(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JButton addRow = new JButton("Add Row");
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                openAddRowPane("Add Row");
            }
        });
        JButton editRow = new JButton("Edit Row");
        editRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                openEditRowPane("Edit Row");
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        TitledBorder buttonBorder = new TitledBorder("Buttons");
        buttonPane.setBorder(buttonBorder);

        buttonPane.add(addRow);
        buttonPane.add(editRow);

        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnIdentifiers);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            model.insertRow(i, data[i]);
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        pane.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        pane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void openAddRowPane(String name){
        //remove to make a new JDiag each time
        //if(addDialog == null){
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
            //if(win != null){ //it is ok if win is null
                addDialog = new JDialog(win, name,    ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                addDialog.getContentPane().add(diagPanel1);
                addDialog.pack();
                addDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            //}
        //}
        addDialog.setVisible(true);
        printRow(diagPanel1.getData());
    }

    public void openEditRowPane(String name){
        //remove to make a new JDiag each time
        //if(editDialog == null){
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
            //if(win != null){//it ok if win = null
                editDialog = new JDialog(win, name,    ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                editDialog.getContentPane().add(diagPanel2);
                editDialog.pack();
                editDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            //}
        //}
        editDialog.setVisible(true);
        printRow(diagPanel2.getData());
    }

    public void printRow(Object[] data){

        //add null protection
        if(data == null) {
            return;
        }
        int length = data.length;
        String s = "[";
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(i == (length-1)){
                s += data[i].toString() + "]";
            } else {
                s += data[i].toString() + ", ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCVE");
        Template_StackOverflowExample mainPanel = new     Template_StackOverflowExample();
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

//changed name to start with capital letter
class DialogTemplate extends JPanel{

    private JComponent[] content;
    private String[] labelHeaders = {
        "ID:",
        "IMEI:",
    };

    private Object[] lastData;

    public DialogTemplate(){
        JPanel diagTemplate = new JPanel();
        diagTemplate.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel rowContent = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        JLabel idLabel = null;
        JLabel imeiLabel = null;

        JLabel[] labels = {
            idLabel,
            imeiLabel,
        };

        JTextField idTextField = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField imeiTextField = new JTextField(20);

        content = new JComponent[] {
            idTextField,
            imeiTextField,
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
            labels[i] = new JLabel(labelHeaders[i]);
            rowContent.add(labels[i]);
            rowContent.add(content[i]);
            labels[i].setLabelFor(content[i]);
        }

        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveData();
                closeWindow();
            }
        });
        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                closeWindow();
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        buttonPane.add(save);
        buttonPane.add(cancel);

        buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        diagTemplate.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        diagTemplate.add(rowContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(diagTemplate);
    }

    public void saveData(){
        lastData = new Object[content.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < lastData.length; i++){
            if(content[i] instanceof JTextField){
                JTextField temp = (JTextField) content[i];
                lastData[i] = temp.getText();
            }
        }
    }

    public Object[] getData(){
        return lastData;
    }

    public void closeWindow(){
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        if(win != null) {
            win.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

(BTW: Why do you want to open a new diag every time ? )

To address you second question I added a JDialog sub - class, with getData() functionality. See comments :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Template_StackOverflowExample extends JPanel{

    //changed type to DialogTemplate so you can use getData()
    //Alternatively you can keep the type as JPanle and cast:
    // ((DialogTemplate)diagPanel1).getData()
    private DialogTemplate diagPanel1 = new DialogTemplate();
    private DialogTemplate diagPanel2 = new DialogTemplate();

    Object[] columnIdentifiers = {
            "id",
            "imei",
    };

    Object[][] data = {
            {"1", "123"},
            {"2", "123"},
            {"3", "123"}
    };

    //changed type to JDialog subclass
    private Dialog addDialog;
    private Dialog editDialog;

    private static DefaultTableModel model;
    private JTable table;

    public Template_StackOverflowExample(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JButton addRow = new JButton("Add Row");
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addDialog = openDialog("Add Row");
                Object[] getData = addDialog.getData();
                printRow(getData);
            }
        });
        JButton editRow = new JButton("Edit Row");
        editRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                editDialog = openDialog("Edit Row");
                Object[] getData = editDialog.getData();
                printRow(getData);

            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        TitledBorder buttonBorder = new TitledBorder("Buttons");
        buttonPane.setBorder(buttonBorder);

        buttonPane.add(addRow);
        buttonPane.add(editRow);

        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnIdentifiers);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            model.insertRow(i, data[i]);
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        pane.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        pane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public Dialog openDialog(String name){

        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        return new Dialog(win, new DialogTemplate(), name);
    }

    public void printRow(Object[] data){

        //add null protection
        if(data == null) {
            return;
        }
        int length = data.length;
        String s = "[";
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(i == (length-1)){
                s += data[i].toString() + "]";
            } else {
                s += data[i].toString() + ", ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MCVE");
        Template_StackOverflowExample mainPanel = new     Template_StackOverflowExample();
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

//subclassed JDialog to add get data functionality
class Dialog extends JDialog {

    DialogTemplate diagPanel;

    Dialog(Window win, DialogTemplate diagPanel, String name) {

        super(win, name,  ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        this.diagPanel = diagPanel;
        getContentPane().add(diagPanel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    Object[] getData(){
        return diagPanel.getData();
    }
}


//changed name to start with capital letter
class DialogTemplate extends JPanel{

    private JComponent[] content;
    private String[] labelHeaders = {
            "ID:",
            "IMEI:",
    };

    private Object[] lastData;

    public DialogTemplate(){
        JPanel diagTemplate = new JPanel();
        diagTemplate.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel rowContent = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        JLabel idLabel = null;
        JLabel imeiLabel = null;

        JLabel[] labels = {
                idLabel,
                imeiLabel,
        };

        JTextField idTextField = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField imeiTextField = new JTextField(20);

        content = new JComponent[] {
                idTextField,
                imeiTextField,
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
            labels[i] = new JLabel(labelHeaders[i]);
            rowContent.add(labels[i]);
            rowContent.add(content[i]);
            labels[i].setLabelFor(content[i]);
        }

        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveData();
                closeWindow();
            }
        });
        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                closeWindow();
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        buttonPane.add(save);
        buttonPane.add(cancel);

        buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        diagTemplate.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        diagTemplate.add(rowContent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(diagTemplate);
    }

    public void saveData(){
        lastData = new Object[content.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < lastData.length; i++){
            if(content[i] instanceof JTextField){
                JTextField temp = (JTextField) content[i];
                lastData[i] = temp.getText();
            }
        }
    }

    public Object[] getData(){
        return lastData;
    }

    public void closeWindow(){
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        if(win != null) {
            win.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers. I fixed the compilation errors in the top post as well. I already fixed my problem, but I see some nice changes in your suggestion that I want to implement, such as the sub class of JDialog. I created a few methods, one for clearing the JDialog and one for resetting the data once I had "grabbed" it. I will make a reply with the code once I have adapted it to your suggestion. DW. Yours will be marked as the answer ;)

Comment: Furthermore I originally thought that creating a new dialog would be a good way to make sure that the panel didn't contain anything when it was newly created. However using a `reset()` method works better imo.

Comment: Thanks for the vote (0: . I copied the first code from my answer and run it again. I get printout from both buttons. Did you do any changes ? BTW1 : I assume you do know that you can make the table itself editable. BTW2: In edit mode you could load the JDialog with the current data from the relevant row. BTW3: to get more and faster response you could keep the MCVE to M. For example in this code MCVE with one button is enough.

Comment: After I had written that it didn't work I tried it again and suddenly it seemed to work. I did exactly what you suggested and loaded the dialog with the data for the edit dialog.

I will remember keeping my questions to the bare minimum in the future. Once again thanks! :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a TableModel and add the data to the model. Then for populating the data for edit. User would select the row and click on edit so in that case you can get the selected row from the model and load it in the Dialog which you show when you edit. I have not given any code in the answer. Let me know if you need help with the code.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I already have this part of the code working. It is the saving of data and opening new panels that is my problem.